# STDOUT and STDERR From a COM Exe

Tags: com

I am creating an exe COM component using CoCreateInstance but I would like the STDOUT and STDERR for that COM exe process to be redirected to a file that I specify.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Google "freopen stdout".  Bad idea btw, a COM server should not be a console mode app.

Comment: Thanks Hans, why should a COM server not be a console app?